# Bounded Poisson Random Walk

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose we have the following random walk.  Let $X_0=\lambda \in \mathbb{N}$ and then

$ \begin{cases} 
      X_t=\operatorname{Pois}(1) & \text{if } X_{t-1}=0 \\
      X_t=\operatorname{Pois}(X_{t-1}) & \text{if } 1 \leq X_{t-1} \leq \lambda \\
      X_t=\operatorname{Pois}(\lambda) & \text{if } X_{t-1}>\lambda 
   \end{cases}
$

From running simulations, it appears that for $t,λ$ large, $X_t$ is very rarely $>λ$. I'd like to prove something precise along these lines. Maybe that, as $t,\lambda \to \infty$, $\mathbb{P}(X_t>\lambda) \to 0$. (but I'm not wedded to this exact question, I'm more interested in learning how one would go about analyzing this, rather than answering a specific question)

I also posted this to stats.stackexchange, but I think it may be a better fit here.

Comment: Possible Duplicate.. (though no answers) [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219845/bounded-poisson-random-walk)

Comment: Dont post the same question in 2 different sites...

Comment: I said it was a duplicate in my post.  I posted to stats yesterday, didn't get much response, and after looking at poisson related questions from both sites, it seemed that a theoretical question like this this would be a much better fit here.  Was this unreasonable?

Comment: No. Check this [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Ok, I deleted the question on stats